# Create a bundle app from a jar that requires Java 1.8

Tags: java, macos, ant, jar, bundle

I'm struggling with the delivery of a java application. I wrote it with Eclupse Luna, and I managed to export a jar with external files (images). So that now I have an ant build xml file from Eclipse, I can run `ant -buildfile projectANT.xml` and I can double click on the jar file to execute it only after have copied the data file with all external images.

Now I want to create a Mac bundle, so that a project.app that have an icon, can be added to the Dock and can contains the java jdk inside it (no java installation required). I'm using Java 1.8.

I've tried to get a bundle from an existing application and put my jar into it (with all files and the jdk and everything else) but I get `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810`.

Then I tried to use JarBundler 2.3.1 coping the jar bundler inside the ant lib folder but I didn't manage to create a correct ant file, it always end up with some missing under fined properties like:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type jarbundler
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Then I tried to launch `Jar Bundler` from the apple development tools version 14.5.0 but It cannot load my jar file (no error.. just anything appear in `Main class` after selecting it and the button `Create Application` just stay grey and I cannot click on it.

I also tried to create a bundle from a script where I invoke `java project.jar` following this [blog post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) but seems to be too old and does not work on my Mac OS/X (10.8.5).

Any advice? Is there a simple way to create a Java application with Java 1.8 from an jar exported with Eclipse?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem would you please share your solution? did you find anything at all? my question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207295/failed-to-bundle-java-application-1-8-for-mac   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can modify the contents of an existing Mac Bundle, intuition tells me that there's security features to prevent that, it would be too easy to modify an existing bundle with malicious code.  You'll need to start back with your ant task and make a fresh Mac Bundle.
Follow this Link "[Build Mac OSX Java Application](http://alvinalexander.com/java/how-to-build-mac-osx-java-application-example)" and you will find it contains a fantastic ant task example and write up about how to do exactly how to accomplish this using the ant task.

Here is the example from his article

```
 <target name="create-bundle" depends="clean">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="${release.dir}"
        name="appName"
        displayname="displayName"
        identifier="com.your.app.Main"
        shortversion="0.1"
        icon="app.icns"
        copyright="Your Name"
        applicationCategory="public.app-category.utilities"
        mainclassname="com/your/app/Main"
    >
        <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
        <!-- may want to also reference dependent jars using a classpath ref-->
        <classpath file="path/to/your/jar" />
        <option value="-Xdock:icon=Contents/Resources/youricon.icns"/>
        <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
        <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages=true"/>
        <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
        <option value="-Dapple.awt.application.name=appName"/>
        <option value="-Dcom.apple.smallTabs=true"/>

    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

Make sure that you set the bundle to open with java 1.8 runtime
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130692

Comment: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/alberto/Code/woodskin/build/appName.app.` again.. what does 10810 means? I don't find a lot in the google

Comment: Looks like you're almost there.  I think you may need to associate the package with the java runtime; but make sure you have java 1.8 installed on your mac.

Comment: `java -version > java version "1.8.0_11"` what does it means? It seems the same problem I had before..

Comment: if you open up a command line and type "java -version" the command prints out the version of java within that terminal.  Could you be a bit more descriptive where you see this problem?

Comment: @kayakMike Hi I have similar question please have a look at my question thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207295/failed-to-bundle-java-application-1-8-for-mac